# AWS execute API request using QT 5

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, qt

i am trying to create an API request to an AWS API, right now i fix the first issue that is related to generate de signature version 4, but no matter what i do, AWS response tell me that the signature is not welll generated, i already check the signature using nodejs code and works, according what i see and what AWS SUpport say, it is possible that some request headers are missing.

I am adding my QT Code i know that is not the best but is only an example, the function that i using to make the post request is loginWekall

```
#include "hash.h"
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QNetworkReply>
CryptoHash::CryptoHash(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString CryptoHash::getKey(){
    return this->key;
}
void CryptoHash::setKey(QString key){
    this->key = key;
}
void CryptoHash::setSecret(QString secret){
    this->secret = secret;
}
void CryptoHash::setRegion(QString region){
    this->region = region;
}
void CryptoHash::setMethod(QString method){
    this->method = method;
}
void CryptoHash::setEndpoint(QString endpoint){
    this->endpoint = endpoint;
}
void CryptoHash::setHost(QString host){
    this->host = host;
}
void CryptoHash::setURL(QString URL){
    this->url = URL;
}



QString CryptoHash::getHash() {
    return this->hashvalue;
}

const QByteArray CryptoHash::getSignatureKey(QString datestamp) {
    QMessageAuthenticationCode code(QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
    code.setKey(datestamp.toUtf8());
    code.addData("AWS4" + this->key.toUtf8());
    QByteArray kDate = code.result();
    code.reset();
    code.setKey(this->region.toUtf8());
    code.addData(kDate);
    QByteArray kRegion = code.result();
    code.reset();
    code.setKey(this->service.toUtf8());
    code.addData(kRegion);
    QByteArray kService = code.result();
    code.reset();
    code.setKey("aws4_request");
    code.addData(kService);
    const QByteArray kSignin = code.result();
    return kSignin;



}

QByteArray CryptoHash::algorithmDesignation(const QCryptographicHash::Algorithm algorithm) {
    switch (algorithm) {
        case QCryptographicHash::Md4:      return "AWS4-HMAC-MD4";
        case QCryptographicHash::Md5:      return "AWS4-HMAC-MD5";
        case QCryptographicHash::Sha1:     return "AWS4-HMAC-SHA1";
        case QCryptographicHash::Sha224:   return "AWS4-HMAC-SHA224";
        case QCryptographicHash::Sha256:   return "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
        case QCryptographicHash::Sha384:   return "AWS4-HMAC-SHA384";
        case QCryptographicHash::Sha512:   return "AWS4-HMAC-SHA512";
        default:
            Q_ASSERT_X(false, Q_FUNC_INFO, "invalid algorithm");
            return "invalid-algorithm";
    }
}

QByteArray CryptoHash::canonicalHeader(const QByteArray &headerName, const QByteArray &headerValue) {
    QByteArray header = headerName.toLower() + ':';
    const QByteArray trimmedHeaderValue = headerValue.trimmed();
    bool isInQuotes = false;
    char previousChar = '\0';
    for (int index = 0; index < trimmedHeaderValue.size(); ++index) {
        char thisChar = trimmedHeaderValue.at(index);
        header += thisChar;
        if (isInQuotes) {
            if ((thisChar == '"') && (previousChar != '\\'))
                isInQuotes = false;
        } else {
            if ((thisChar == '"') && (previousChar != '\\')) {
                isInQuotes = true;
            } else if (isspace(thisChar)) {
                while ((index < trimmedHeaderValue.size()-1) &&
                       (isspace(trimmedHeaderValue.at(index+1))))
                    ++index;
            }
        }
        previousChar = thisChar;
    }
    return header;
}

QByteArray CryptoHash::canonicalHeaders(const QNetworkRequest &request, QByteArray * const signedHeaders) {
    Q_CHECK_PTR(signedHeaders);
    signedHeaders->clear();


    QMap<QByteArray,QByteArray> headers;
    foreach (const QByteArray &rawHeader, request.rawHeaderList()) {
        headers.insert(rawHeader.toLower(), request.rawHeader(rawHeader));
    }

    headers.insert("host", request.url().host().toUtf8());
    headers.insert("x-amz-date", this->amz.toUtf8());

    QByteArray canonicalHeaders;
    for (QMap<QByteArray,QByteArray>::const_iterator iter = headers.constBegin(); iter != headers.constEnd(); ++iter) {
        canonicalHeaders += canonicalHeader(iter.key(), iter.value()) + '\n';
        if (!signedHeaders->isEmpty()) *signedHeaders += ';';
        *signedHeaders += iter.key();
    }
    return canonicalHeaders;
}

QByteArray CryptoHash::canonicalRequest(const QNetworkAccessManager::Operation operation,
                                        const QNetworkRequest &request,
                                        const QByteArray &payload,
                                        QByteArray * const signedHeaders) {


    //qInfo() <<"payload";
    //qInfo() << payload;
    //qInfo() << QCryptographicHash::hash(payload, QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toHex();
    return this->method.toUtf8() + '\n' +
           this->endpoint.toUtf8() + '\n' +
           "\n" + canonicalHeaders(request, signedHeaders) + '\n' +
           *signedHeaders + '\n' +
           QCryptographicHash::hash(payload, QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toHex();
}

QByteArray CryptoHash::credentialScope(const QDateTime &date, const QString &region, const QString &service) {
    return this->dstamp.toUtf8() + '/' + region.toUtf8() + '/' + service.toUtf8() + "/aws4_request";
}

QByteArray CryptoHash::stringToSign(const QByteArray &algorithmDesignation, const QString &requestDate,
                                               const QByteArray &credentialScope, const QByteArray &canonicalRequest) {

    return algorithmDesignation + '\n' +
           this->amz.toUtf8() + '\n' +
           credentialScope + '\n' +
           QCryptographicHash::hash(canonicalRequest, QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toHex();
}

QByteArray CryptoHash::signingKey( const QDate &date,
                                             const QString &region, const QString &service) {

    const QCryptographicHash::Algorithm hashAlgorithm = QCryptographicHash::Sha256;
    return QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash("aws4_request",
              QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(service.toUtf8(),
              QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(region.toUtf8(),
              QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(this->dstamp.toUtf8(), "AWS4"+this->secret.toUtf8(),
              hashAlgorithm), hashAlgorithm), hashAlgorithm), hashAlgorithm);
}
void debugRequest(QNetworkRequest request, QByteArray data = QByteArray())
{

  qDebug() << request.url().toString();
  const QList<QByteArray>& rawHeaderList(request.rawHeaderList());
  foreach (QByteArray rawHeader, rawHeaderList) {
    qDebug() << request.rawHeader(rawHeader);
  }
  qDebug() << data;

}
QString CryptoHash::loginWekall(const QString AWSV4, const QString timestamp){
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager  = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url("https://asdasdasd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/master/users/login");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QJsonObject obj;
    obj["email"] = "user@test.co";
    obj["password"] = "password";
    QJsonDocument doc(obj);
    QByteArray data = doc.toJson();
    // FIXME for debug
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", AWSV4.toUtf8());
    request.setRawHeader("X-Amz-Date", this->amz.toUtf8());
    request.setRawHeader("Host","g298zqijvh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept","application/json, text/plain, */*");
    qDebug() << request.url().toString();
    const QList<QByteArray>& rawHeaderList(request.rawHeaderList());
    foreach (QByteArray rawHeader, rawHeaderList) {
      qDebug() << request.rawHeader(rawHeader);
    }
    qDebug() << data;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, data);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=](){
        if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
            QString contents = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
            qDebug() << contents;
        }
        else{
            qInfo()<< QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
            QString err = reply->errorString();
            qDebug() << err;
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
    });


    return "true";
}
QString CryptoHash::getDate(){
    return this->amz;
}
QString CryptoHash::hash(){
    const QDateTime datetime;
    QDateTime* dtime = new QDateTime();
    QString amzdate = dtime->currentDateTimeUtc().toString("yyyyMMddThhmmssZ").toUtf8();
    QString datestamp = dtime->currentDateTimeUtc().toString("yyyyMMdd").toUtf8();
    QJsonObject data;
    this->amz = amzdate;
    //this->amz = "20210306T142037Z";
    this->dstamp = datestamp;
    qInfo() <<"amztime";
    qInfo() << amzdate;
    qInfo() <<"date";
    qInfo() << datestamp;

    data["email"] = "user@test.co";
    data["password"] = "password";
    QJsonDocument doc(data);
    QByteArray strData(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));
    qInfo() << "JSON parameters";
    qInfo() << strData;





    const QByteArray algorithmDesignation = this->algorithmDesignation(QCryptographicHash::Sha256);

    const QString endpoint = this->endpoint;

    QString signa = "host;x-amz-date";;


    const QByteArray credentialScope = this->credentialScope(datetime, this->region, this->service);
    QString access = "ACCESSKEYID/";
    this->scope =  access.toUtf8() + this->dstamp+ "/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request";
    qInfo() << "credentialScope";
    qInfo() << credentialScope;
    QByteArray signedHeaders = signa.toUtf8();
    qInfo() << "signedHeaders";
    qInfo() << signedHeaders;
    const QUrl URL("https://asdasd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/master/users/login");
    const QNetworkRequest request(URL);

    const QByteArray canonicalRequest = this->canonicalRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation::PostOperation, request, strData, &signedHeaders);
    qInfo() << "canonical request";
    qInfo() << canonicalRequest;
    const QByteArray stringToSign = this->stringToSign(algorithmDesignation, this->amz, credentialScope, canonicalRequest);
    qInfo() << "stringToSign";
    qInfo() << stringToSign;
    const QByteArray signingKey = this->signingKey(datetime.date(), this->region, this->service);
    qInfo() << "signinKey";
    qInfo() << signingKey;

    const QByteArray signature = QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(stringToSign, signingKey, QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
    qInfo() << "signature";
    qInfo() << signature;
    this->hashvalue = algorithmDesignation + " Credential=" + this->key.toUtf8() + '/' + credentialScope +
                ", SignedHeaders=" + signedHeaders + ", Signature=" + signature.toHex();
    qInfo() << "AWS SIGNATURE VERSION 4";
    qInfo() << this->hashvalue;
    this->loginWekall(hashvalue, this->amz);
    return 0;
}

CryptoHash::~CryptoHash(){};
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the C++ aws sdk?

Comment: @jordanm so as to use the Qt network stack rather than libcurl I'd guess. Using the Qt stack means nice event / I/O multiplexing integration with the rest of your code.